# How to give my RStudio server "sudo" access?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I tried to `dir.create` on a path that I need `sudo` access to create directories. But I can't seem to do it from Rstudio server instance of Rstudio that I access from the browser, even though I started the Rstudio server using `sudo rstudio-server start`.

Is there a way to give my Rstudio instance `sudo` powers?

Comment: xiaodai, I can think of no better way to provide unfettered access to your underlying OS to the masses of curious script-kiddies out there than to give R (within RStudio Server) `sudo` access. (Said a better way: perhaps you should ask about the actual thing you're trying to do ... trying to solve it with `sudo` either (a) is absolutely the wrong way, or (b) suggests a big piece is missing from the server.)

Comment: BTW: running the server with `sudo` should mean nothing: servers that require exposing a port below 1024 traditionally require root access, and sometimes they need root access for other services/resources ... but as soon as they get what they need, "best practices" in server development is to drop privileges as soon as you don't need them. With anything that is "forked" (process-wise), this often means the child process does not need or receive most or any of the privileged access.

Comment: It's curious, because the SSD on a private server is mounted on `/` so to use it I need to write to it. That's why I need `sudo` access.

Comment: Up front, I don't have an easy answer for you, but please understand that I don't say this casually: sandboxing and compartmentalization of processes (server or otherwise) is a very important thing for security, so often server-applications try very hard to specifically forbid access to directories outside of its control. Within the `shiny`, there are ways to write to the local filesystem within the shiny-app itself, but anything outside of that gets risky. And since this is really a confluence of R and javascript, there are likely undiscovered security holes lurking, so ... paranoia is good.

Comment: So while that previous statement may not be new to you in general (or perhaps it is), know that the reason you do not have access to it is likely one of: (1) you have not configured RStudio Server to consider it safe for users/apps to write to that directory; or (2) the underlying OS does not know this yet. If the OS knows but RStudio does not allow it, then it might be a feature-request ...

Answer (score 2):

When you use the RStudio Server web client, it executes local scripts as the "rstudio-server" user on your Linux machine (run `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` to list local users and it will appear there). You need to ensure that the rstudio-server user and the user you log onto the client with has rwx permissions across the directories you want to make changes in from RStudio.

```
sudo setfacl -m u:rstudio-server:rwx /path/
sudo setfacl -m u:localuser:rwx /path/
```